# How to get g++ for Linux FC-14

Tags: linux, g++, installation, gnu-make

I am trying to install some software using gmake (recommended by author) on a FC14 machine.  gmake fails when trying to call /usr/bin/g++, and there is no g++ in /usr/bin.

I have the "various compilers" package installed. When I search on "g++" for available packages using the gnome Add/Remove Software interface, I get two choices "Cross Compiling GNU G++ targeted at arm-gp2-linux" and "Cross Compiling GNU GCC targeted at avr."

I don't have an ARM processor and I don't know what avr is, so I'm wondering if one of these is the right package, or if I need something else.  Anyone have guidance?

Comment: Please [don't add signatures or taglines to your posts](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#signatures).

Answer (score 2):

I don't know about Fedora 14, but at least on RHEL-5 (based on an older Fedora release) the package you want is "gcc-c++"

Comment: That (C++ Support for GCC) did it. The "Various compilers" lists C++ so I thought that was all I needed. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Do a search for "gcc" instead of "g++" it's usually in that package or "gcc-c++".